Gradle Init Java Library is failing to resolve dependencies for lib "target"
I have Java 17 on my machine and Gradle 8.3.
I create a new Java Library project using:
gradle init --type java-library

I follow the prompts and it produces a project with a directory structure that looks like:
myapp/
  lib/
    src/main/java/<some-generated-java-code-here>
    build.gradle
  gradle.properties
  settings.gradle

I run gradle wrapper, and then I go into build.gradle and add a few dependencies, making it look like:
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

group 'me.myself'
version '24.0.2'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    implementation (
            'com.google.guava:guava:32.1.1-jre'

            ,'org.keycloak:keycloak-core'
            ,'org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi'
            ,'org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi-private'
            ,'org.keycloak:keycloak-services'
            ,'org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging'
            ,'org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec'
    )
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'myapp-keycloak-customizer'
    archiveVersion = '24.0.2'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

Inside IntelliJ I go to build the project, just to pull in/resolve the new dependencies, and I get the following error:
:lib:main: Could not find org.keycloak:keycloak-core:.
Required by:
    project :lib

I have verified that org.keycloak:keycloak-core is a valid entry for Maven Central. Also, as you'll see below, it can't even find JBoss Logging, so its not a Maven or Keycloak dependency issue. I can also verify I have full wifi and no networking issues.
So from the terminal I run ./gradlew build --debug and I get a ton of output, the interesting portion being:
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter] 
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':lib:compileJava'.
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':lib:compileClasspath'.
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not find org.keycloak:keycloak-core:.
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :lib
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not find org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi:.
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :lib
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not find org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi-private:.
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :lib
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not find org.keycloak:keycloak-services:.
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :lib
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not find org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:.
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :lib
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not find org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec:.
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
[ERROR] [o.g.i.b.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :lib

Its almost as if its looking in the lib directory for my dependencies instead of pulling them from Maven Central maybe? Can anyone spot where I'm going awry and help me get this thing building please?

You need to call implementation for each library, and supply the version each time.
dependencies {
    def keycloakVersion = '24.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:32.1.1-jre'
    implementation "org.keycloak:keycloak-core:$keycloakVersion"
    implementation "org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi:$keycloakVersion"
    //...
}

We're using some Groovy features there, namely defining a variable and string interpolation.

Oof, that was it thanks! The way I defined the dependencies inside a shared implementation block used to be legal, was that removed from Gradle at some point (very) recently?

I've never seen such a notation. One for the historians maybe

Nah I'm using it in another Gradle 8.3 project and have been using it for 8+ years now, just not one that was specified as java-library.

Well, the API docs for version 1.0 don't look that different to those for version 8.7, or version 5.6.4 for that matter, so I will remain sceptical of your claim. I note if you were specifying file names then something like that would be possible, inside of a files() call

java-library makes no difference other than giving the name "implementation" to the configuration. It is possible that another plugin could add its own helper function to allow such a notation, though.

in case you are using JBoss server, you can also try providedCompile for the dependencies which already exist in the JBoss module path by default, such as the logger.
